# Does anyone know why my java code doesn't work properly using n=n/2 while n>>1 does?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

This is a problem from leetcode(https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/). 
This method is for counting the 1s this number has in binary.
I try to use n=n/2 which doesn't pass every case while n=n>>1 does. Does anyone know why??

```
public class Numberof1Bits {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Numberof1Bits()
            .hammingWeight(0b11111111111111111111111111111111));
}

public int hammingWeight(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    if (n < 0)
        count++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        if ((n & 1) == 1)
            count++;
        n = n >> 1;// while this doesn't work when n=n/2;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using >> and not >>>?

Comment: @EJP Yes. I know what you mean. But I pre-counted the sign bit and only count the rest 31 bits.

Comment: `n = n >> 1` does exactly the same thing as `n = n/2`. I suspect you were just lucky to pass the test when you tried it one way.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Come on, you can just run this case yourself. The result is different.

Comment: Give me an example of an integer `n` where `n>>1` is different from `n/2`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Don't you see the main() function?

Comment: @Elizabeth Apologies. You're right. `-1/2` is different from `-1 >> 1`.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. I don't know what 'pre-counted the sign bit' even means. I repeat. Are you really using the `>>` operator? It seems practically certain that you're actually using the `>>>` operator.

Comment: @EJP So the >> means shift while ignoring the sign bit, so the most significant bit will always remain its value. However >>> will treat the int as unsigned while shifting. So in this case, you notice that I only iterate 31 times because I should take extra care of the sign bit. If you use >>>, you can iterate 32 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using unsigned ints. 0xFFFFFFFF = -1. -1 >> 1 = -1. -1/2 = 0. It will fail for any number with the most significant bit set.

If Java, the `>>` operator does a sign-extended bitwise right shift. For example (I use 8 bits digits for clarity's sake):

```
0b10111111 >> 1 => 0b11011111
```

The same in decimal:

```
-65 >> 1 => -33
```

Bits are shifted right by one position, and the most significant bit is kept as is. My example number (0b10111111) is -65 in decimal. If you divide it by two, you get -32. Yes, we've lost one bit in translation. `/2` performs an arithmetic division, which is equivalent to `>> 1` **only** for positive numbers.

In languages that support unsigned ints and an unsigned right shift, n/2 should work as intended.

In java, since `>>` is signed, you could use `>>>` which does a right shift *without* sign extension, and the possibly faster loop:

```
public int hammingWeight(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while(n != 0) {
        if ((n & 1) != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        n = n >>> 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned ints.

Comment: @wldsvc I don't get it. Aren't /2 and >>1 work in the same way. And java don't have unsigned int type.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, I know. In this case, >> and >>> does the same work  cuz I just shift 31 times. My question is why /2 doesn't work?

Comment: No, they don't work the same way on negative numbers. The >>> is what seems to be most useful if you want to count bits.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin But in this case they are the same while I've pre-counted the sign already.

Comment: n/2 doesn't work for the reason that it does a signed division: -1 (all bits set) / 2 = 0. If you need more details, I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1 >> 1) + "\n" + Integer.toBinaryString(-1 / 2))

gives you: 11111111111111111111111111111111 vs
0

Comment: @wldsvc Yes. Can you explain more? I just don't get it why they work differently. And I will mark your answer accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @Elizabeth, answer updated. Since we're dealing with int, there's no rounding involved, just plain integer arithmetic rules and bits.

Comment: @wldsvc And `>>` does a signed shift. This explains nothing.

Comment: signed right shift is not the same as dividing by two for unsigned numbers: `-65 >> 1 = -33` but `-65 / 2 = -32` according to integer arithmetic. Better example yet: `-1 >> 1 = -1` but `-1 / 2 = 0`, signed or not for the latter.

Comment: @wldsvc Thank you. I just got it after showering. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. That was so obvious to me that my initial answer was really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

`>> 1` divides an `int` by two, but the rounding is done using floor, i.e. rounding towards negative infinity. The relevant quote from the Java Language Specification:

> The value of n >> s is n right-shifted s bit positions with
>   sign-extension. The resulting value is floor(n / 2^s).

For example,

```
 20 >> 1 == 10
 15 >> 1 == 7   (7.5 is rounded down to 7)
-20 >> 1 == -10
-15 >> 1 == -8  (-7.5 is rounded down to -8)
```

On the other hand, for `/` the rounding is done towards zero. This is from the Java Language Specification:

> The binary / operator performs division, producing the quotient of its
>   operands. The left-hand operand is the dividend and the right-hand
>   operand is the divisor.
>
> Integer division rounds toward 0.

For example,

```
 20 / 2 == 10
 15 / 2 == 7    (7.5 is rounded down to 7)
-20 / 2 == -10
-15 / 2 == -7   (-7.5 is rounded UP to -7)
```

For negative odd integers `n`, `n /= 2` is therefore the same as `n >>= 1; n++;`. The `n++` will completely change the calculation for the number of set bits.

Comment: @Elizabeth That's ok. My initial confusion was because `n<<1` **is** always the same as `n*2`. I'm also just learning Python where `n//2` does round towards negative infinity. All this is so confusing!